# How can I display view inside content control in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, contentcontrol

FirstView.xaml contains Something like this

```
<ContentControl Name="ContentControlName" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding SelectionViewModel}"/>
```

My SelectionView.xaml contains

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBoxName" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
<TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Uid}"/>
```

In the FirstViewModel I have created a property like below

```
private SelectionViewModel selectionViewModel;
public SelectionViewModel SelectionViewModel
{
    get
    {
        return this.selectionViewModel;
    }
}
```

Content control with two text box is not displayed when I run

Is the way done right?

Comment: what DataTemplates do you have set up?

Comment: ContentControl doesnt show anything
Cant we do without using Data Templates

Answer (score 2):

Since you used binding, you need raise up **PropertyChanged** event. 
Your ViewModel class (SelectionViewModel) must implement **INotifyPropertyChanged**.

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private SelectionViewModel selectionViewModel;

    public SelectionViewModel SelectionViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectionViewModel;
        }
        private set
        {
            this.selectionViewModel = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, nameof(SelectionViewModel));
        }
    }
}
```

You passed SelectionViewModel instance to Content property of ContentControl.
Your ContentControl must have special datatemplate coupled with this view model. Otherwise, it will not work.

For example:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectionViewModel}">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SelectionViewModel}">
            <!-- Here is your template -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

Also you shouldn't use same names for type SelectionViewModel and property SelectionViewModel.

Since you wasn't provide a source code we can't figure out the exact cause of your error.
I hope it was helpful for you.

Comment: SelectionViewModel class has some properties for which I have raised PropertyChanged 
but I dint raise PropertyChanged for SelectionViewModel Property

Comment: I can replace `<Here is Template>` with two textbox in Selection View.. Is that right?
but I need a separate view in

Comment: @Jerry_A do you have two view model? You need MainViewModel for your main window which contains your content control view model (SelectionViewModel property). You must bind your main window to MainViewModel.

Comment: @Jerry_A you could replace <!-- Here is your template --> to your template or insert your custom user control instead it.

Comment: yes Thanks @Noisy88 .. I was expecting something like this 
`<ContentControl >
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Node}" Value="Network">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource A}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Node}" Value="Web">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource B}"/>`

Comment: It can be made easier. Just use <ContentControl.Resources><DataTemplate DataType=...>...</DataTemplate><DataTemplate DataType=...></DataTemplate></ContentControl.Resources>